# Regular Expression doesn't find all the matches

Tags: c#, regex, string

**Edited:**
I have a `string str = "where dog is and cats are and bird is bigger than a mouse"` and want to extract separate substrings between `where` and `and`, `and`and `and`, `and` and the end of the sentence. The result should be: `dog is`, `cats are`, `bird is bigger than a mouse`. (Sample string may contain any substrings between `where` and `and` ect.)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string sample = "where dog is and cats are and bird is bigger than a mouse";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sample, @"where|and\s(?<gr>.+)and|$");
foreach (Match m in matches)
  {
     list.Add(m.Groups["gr"].Value.ToString());
  }
```

But it doesn't work. I know that regular expression is not right, so please help me to correct that. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? Split on `where` and `and` or match `dog is`, `cat is` and `bird is` ? What's the pattern you are looking for ?

Comment: @Rahul I'm trying to extract any substring between `where` and `and`, or `and` and `and`. `dog is` and other are just examples.

Comment: Posting some more examples will be better.

Comment: @Rahul see edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using braces to fix the `|` and a lookbehind:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Solution
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string sample = "where dog is and cats are and bird is bigger than a mouse";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sample, @"(?<=(where|and)\s)(?<gr>.+?)(?=(and|$))");
        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Ksm2G

Output:

```
dog is 
cats are 
bird is bigger than a mouse
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `"\w+ is"`

```
  List<string> list = new List<string>();
string sample = "where dog is and cat is and bird is";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sample, @"\w+ is");
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    list.Add(m.Value.ToString());
}
```

Sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pMMMrU

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to extract any substring between `where` and `and`, or `and` and `and`. Not only `dog is`... can be in that place.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Regex.Split()` method not `Regex.Match()`.

```
    string input = "where dog is and cats are and bird is bigger than a mouse";
    string pattern = "(?:where|and)";  
    string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
    foreach (string match in substrings)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
    }
```

This will split on literal words `where` and `and`.

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/oamAkZ)**

Comment: Although this is a workable solution more details need to be provided by OP. Such as if preceding whitespaces are valid ? or more complex sentences.

Comment: Thanks. It almost works. It matches letters before `where` as well